# Java GUI, painting images on button click

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, paint

I'm having some problems creating a GUI. I want it so what when a button is pushed, the two images will appear on the screen side by side. There will be many more images than just two in the future, possibly hundreds (many very small images) I can add in a button in the Main class but then I can't add an action listener. And when I try and add a button in my GUI class nothing shows up. Also in the action listener I cant call the paint function. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Gui extends JFrame {

    private static JButton startButton;

    BufferedImage img;
    BufferedImage img2;


    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(img2, 30, 0, null);

    }

    public Gui() {
       try {
           img = ImageIO.read(new File("res/a.png"));
           img2 = ImageIO.read(new File("res/b.png"));

       } catch (IOException e) {
       }

       startButton = new JButton("tessttt");
       getContentPane().add(startButton); //this doesn't show up
       Events e = new Events();
       startButton.addActionListener(e);


    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() { //sets size of screen
        if (img == null) {
             return new Dimension(100,100);
        } else {
          // return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null)); //sets size to one image //// change to all images
            return new Dimension(500,500);
       }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Load Image Sample");

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(640, 480);

        f.add(new Gui()); //this is the only time I can call this and the images will show up

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Hello"));
        f.add(panel);   //this will show up but i can't add an action listener if this was a button

        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            f.setVisible(true);
    }



public class Events implements ActionListener {


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            if (e.getSource() == startButton) {

            getContentPane.add(new Gui()); //f.add(newGui()); //this also gives errors

        }


        }
    }


}
```

I got the button to work. In the main class I did this

```
    startButton = new JButton("tessttt");
    f.add(startButton);
    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            f.add(new Gui());
            //f.repaint();
        }
    });
```

SO now the question is how do I call paint? either of those do not work.

first few lines of the error I get

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
    at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You shouldn't change your layout manager after you've added components

Comment: @vandale okay i fixed that still nothing

Comment: `startButton` will not show up because you've overidden paint so that it doesn't draw the button. the first line of paint should be `super.paint(g)`

Comment: @vandale I added that in but still nothing. I even tried completely removing the paint function and still nothing.

Comment: `f.add(new Gui())` will not work as you are not allowed to ad `Window`s to `Container`s

Comment: @vandale Yeah I got that error. So what do I do? I updated the post.

Comment: Don't override `paint` of a top level container `JFrame`. Instead, create a custom component, extending from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method and perform your custom painting here, making sure to call `super.paintComponent` first.  Add this panel and your button, separately, to the frame...

Comment: I thought @vandale told you, don't add a top level container to another top level container...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, `Gui` extends from `JFrame`, but in your `main`, you create a new instance of `JFrame` and try and add and instance of `Gui` to it.

You can't do this.  A top level container can not contain another top level container.

To start with, you should avoid extending from `JFrame` as you are not adding any functionality to it.

Overriding `paint` of top level containers is not advisable, as you have found, doing so can break how painting works very easily.

Instead.

Start by creating a custom component, extending from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method and add your custom painting here, making sure you call `super.paintComponent` first.

This will draw your two images.

Create another custom component, extending from something like `JPanel`, adding your "image" panel and button (and other controls) to it, using what ever layout manager you want and if required, compound layouts.

Finally, create an instance of `JFrame` and add the "controls" panel to it...

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: Okay I did that but I'm confused on how to extend the JFrame to my new panels and calling the ImagePanel from the ButtonPanel. Here is the new code on pastebin http://pastebin.com/617uS8di Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: I'd do it slightly differently.  Basically, I would allow the image pane to changable, that is, provide it with the ability for the new images to be assigned to it. This way you only need to assign the new images and not create a new `ImagePane` - but that's me. Also `startButton` shouldn't be `static`. Remember, `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` by default so you  may not get the results you're expecting, but you should try calling revalidate after adding the `ImagePane`

Comment: @MadProgrzmmer Ah okay, then why am I getting an error when I try to do f. anything in my other classes?

Comment: Try changing `f.add` to `add`